# Geonode Installation Oracle Linux

Tags: python-2.7, web, open-source, gis, osgeo

I am running python 2.7.5 and installing geonode in a Oracle Linux machine. I am following the installation [manual](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/setup_on_centos/install_geonode.html) and I execute the command:

python manage.py migrate

I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 29, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/apps/geonode/geonode/geonode/base/models.py", line 56, in <module>
    from geonode.utils import bbox_to_wkt
  File "/opt/apps/geonode/geonode/geonode/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    from slugify import Slugify
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slugify/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from slugify.main import Slugify, UniqueSlugify
ImportError: No module named main
```

Any tip on how to solve this issue?

Thank you for your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved in awesome-slugify 1.6.5 just change its version in geonode/requirements.txt.

N.B: geonode 2.8 is released and the link you follow is not up to date, follow [this](http://docs.geonode.org/en/latest/tutorials/install_and_admin/geonode_install/install_geonode_application.html) to get geonode 2.8